# Errors during Code First add-migration

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012

Our add-migrations are failing routinely but not consistently. The migration always gets to the scaffolding step and then roughly 4 out of 5 times we will receive something like the following:

```
 System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Object '/2355037d_df43_460b_8737_725c0c1c80be/hvdculybngjc_rcnskixmk7+_2.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.at EnvDTE.Project.get_Properties()
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T]  (Project project, String propertyName)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.AddFile(Project project, String path, String contents)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationWriter.Write(ScaffoldedMigration scaffoldedMigration, Boolean rescaffolding, Boolean force, String name)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1()
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Object '/2355037d_df43_460b_8737_725c0c1c80be/hvdculybngjc_rcnskixmk7+_2.rem' has been  disconnected or does not exist at the server.
```

Sometimes the migration class gets generated anyway but more often it does not. Searches on this error have indicated that something is being garbage collected that isn't supposed to be but that doesn't really help us work around the issue.

Our data migration project is in .NET 4.5 with EF 5 working in Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 33):

This happened to me on some long running scripts that generated new indexes.  The workaround that we used was to use:

```
update-database -Script
```

EF then spits out the SQL migration to the screen and then we could run the SQL directly from the server so there were no timeout problems.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had a migration which failed the same way as the OP's migration, apparently due to timeout, and your solution has helped me a lot!