# Simple Linq expression producing bloated where clause that doesn't make sense to me

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, linqkit

I am trying to use this Linq expression

```
Dim ex2 As Expression(Of Func(Of Advertisement, Boolean)) =
    Function(a) a.Address.CountryCode = ISO AndAlso a.Address.Region = EmptyString
```

in this manner

```
Dim ltest = (From a In db.Advertisements.AsExpandable().Where(ex2)).ToList
```

but it produces these crazy where conditions

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 NVARCHAR (MAX) = N'US';
DECLARE @p__linq__1 NVARCHAR (MAX) = N'';
SELECT [Extent1].[AdvertisementID] AS [AdvertisementID],
       [Extent1].[URL] AS [URL],
       [Extent1].[Address_AddressID] AS [Address_AddressID],
       [Extent1].[Business_BusinessID] AS [Business_BusinessID]
FROM [dbo].[Advertisements] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent2]
             ON [Extent1].[Address_AddressID] = [Extent2].[AddressID]
WHERE (([Extent2].[CountryCode] = @p__linq__0)
       OR (([Extent2].[CountryCode] IS NULL)
           AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
  AND (([Extent2].[Region] = @p__linq__1)
       OR (([Extent2].[Region] IS NULL)
           AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))
```

I don't know why it produces `@p__linq__1 IS NULL` when my parameters are strings and not nullables.

I expect it to produce something like

```
WHERE [Extent2].[CountryCode] = @p__linq__0 AND [Extent2].[Region] = @p__linq__1
```

I tried the same thing using LinqKit predicates instead of expressions but got the same results. I actually have a much more complex query with additional where clauses but when it didn't work i broke it down to just this simple query and found the where clause was nothing like what I intended.

So the question is what is the proper way to produce a simpler where clause similar to what I entended using LinqKit expressions or predicates?

Comment: Is the field Advertisements.CountryCode nullable in the database?

Comment: Advertisements.Address_AddressID could be null although Addresses.CountryCode is not null. But if my string @p__linq__0 cannot be null then why would it include that in the query when it can never be true? Why not just omit these repeating pieces OR (([Extent2].[CountryCode] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))

Comment: "my parameters are strings and not nullables" - but strings are reference types - they're inherently nullable.

Comment: Is there something similar to a string that I can use that cant be null that might remove the additional sql? When debugging the SQL I have to first remove the extra items before I can understand whats going on. Anything you could suggest to help simplify it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Entity Framework 6 generate complex SQL queries for simple lookups?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107016/why-does-entity-framework-6-generate-complex-sql-queries-for-simple-lookups)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something similar to a string that I can use that cant be null that might remove the additional sql?

You could try adding a requirement to the expression that guarantees that the string is not null:

```
a.Address.CountryCode = ISO _
    AndAlso Not EmptyString Is Nothing _
    AndAlso a.Address.Region = EmptyString
```

However, the SQL generated by EF is meant to *exactly* represent the expressions passed in (including the differences in null semantics) and not necessarily to be fully optimized or human readable.  Meaning that the SQL generator may not generate the *exact* sql that you expect by adding that requirement.

Or, if`EmptyString` is a "constant" value that is literally an empty string, you could try using `String.Empty` instead.  The interpreter may use the constant value in the query instead of using a parameter.