# EF Migration times out when changing schema of large database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Initially I got `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.` error when tried to run migration which changes field type of table that contains >9m records, which I was able to fix by increasing `DbMigrationsConfiguration.CommandTimeout` value to 200000 (not sure in which units it measured, assumed ms).

And I seen that migration progressed a bit further, however that still doesn't seem enough and migration fails, but with different error `Object '/XXXX/XXXXX.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.`.

Can somebody explain what is `/XXXX/XXXXX.rem` (original name doesn't make any sense it looks like a GUID)?
And how I can prevent `/XXXX/XXXXX.rem` from being disconnected to allow my migration complete.

Comment: Looks like this is a [common problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004239/ef-code-first-migration-error-object-has-been-disconnected-or-does-not-exist-at) with long running migrations in EF. Your `/XXXX/XXXXX.rem` error is because migrations use remoting to execute and the remoting call is timing out. Useful, eh? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22457395/871146) might help - effectively generate the script for your DB and run it in SSMS by hand. Sucks, but might be your only workaround :(